# What should I use in place of SetTexture from d3d9, in case of d3d11?

Tags: directx

I have multiple textures and I have to use them into stages in d3d11. SetTexture is used in case of d3d9, but what should I use in d3d11?

Comment: You should refer to this tutorial for texturing in D3D 11: https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-11-textures

Comment: Direct3D 11 is basically a slightly newer version of Direct3D 10 from the API design perspective. As such, you may find [this migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-d3d9-to-d3d10-considerations) useful going from Direct3D 9 to Direct3D 11.

Answer (score 2):

You have now to bind resources to specific pipeline stages instead of binding to  samplers. Use `SetShaderResources` methods of device context. For example `ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources()` to bind it to pixel shader stage.

To bind texture to pipeline you have to create [shader resource view](https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/nn-d3d11-id3d11shaderresourceview) and pass it to above methods.